# Code target issue

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a website that sits at http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/mcc/default.aspx this works fine when I'. pointing to it at the address.

However the mcc folder is a secure folder and to make it secure the address is https://secure17.prositehosting.co.uk/mcc/default.aspx but when I point to this it does not work.

The problem is a line of code that I'm using in default.aspx and that is

`</asp:DropDownList><asp:AccessDataSource ID="School_DS" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/MockCourt_db.mdb"`

I believe that the `</asp:DropDownList><asp:AccessDataSource ID="School_DS" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/MockCourt_db.mdb"` is saying that the database is at this location but now that I have moved to  secure17.prositehosting.co.uk instead of www.mockcourt.org.uk this is no longer valid.

Does anyone know what I should change the code to so it points to http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/App_Data/MockCourt.db

Comment: You might want to double check firstly that the file is in the app_data directory as you are expecting (in case it didn't get copied over with the rest of the site). Secondly check the filename. your code and where you said the code should be are different. I would imagine you can easily work out how to change from `MockCourt_db.mdb` to `MockCourt.db` if that is really what you need to do...

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute URL to the data file?

```
</asp:DropDownList><asp:AccessDataSource ID="School_DS" runat="server" DataFile="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/App_Data/MockCourt.mdb"
```

Comment: I noticed there was a typo in the file extension of the database file. .MDB is used in the code and then .DB is used in the last URL you provided. Make sure it is correct and consistent, whichever extension it should be (.MDB I am guessing).